# Strange behaviour of ifnumequal?

Tags: macros, etoolbox

If I use `\cfoot` to evaluate and print this section counter, it shows the correct section number in my appendix.

However, when I evaluate the section counter using `\ifnumequal`, it shows that the expression of equality is **never** met. Why?

A not so minimum example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref} 

\newrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionTitle}{}%
\newrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionTitle}%

\newcommand{\Contentsname}{Inhoudsopgave}
\newcommand{\LinkToContentsName}{inhoudsopgave}
\newcommand{\LinkToIndexName}{Index}

\newrobustcmd{\GotoName}{Naar}
\newrobustcmd{\DoIfNumInequal}[3]{%
\ifnumequal{#1}{#2}{}{#3}%  Drop last 
}%
\newrobustcmd{\IfNumInequal}[4]{%
\ifnumequal{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%  
}%


\newcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}% No resetting%%%
\setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{0}%
\newcounter{NextSectionCounter}% No resetting%%%
\setcounter{NextSectionCounter}{0}
\newcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}% No resetting%%%
\setcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}{0}
\newcounter{LastSectionValue}       

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
                    \lfoot{\CurrentSectionTitle}

\fancypagestyle{FootLinks}{
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\makeatletter
\def\LastSectionInFile{%
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string
     \setcounter{LastSectionValue}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}%
   }%
}%
\makeatother
}%

\newrobustcmd{\NextSectionHyperLinkFormat}[1]{\GotoName~#1~\(\rightarrow\)}%
\newrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionHyperLinkFormat}[1]{\(\leftarrow\)~\GotoName~#1}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\newpage


    \let\LaTeXStandardSection\section%
    \renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{CurrentSectionCounter}%
    %%%%% Check first whether there is a already a previous section
    \ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{1}{% Yes, section number is zero
    \setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{1}%
    \expandafter\renewrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionTitle}{%
    #2}%
    }{%
    \makeatletter
    \edef\@@oldtitle{\CurrentSectionTitle}
    \expandafter\renewrobustcmd{\PreviousSectionTitle}{%
    \@@oldtitle
    }%
    \expandafter\renewrobustcmd{\CurrentSectionTitle}{%
    #2%
    }%
    \setcounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}
    \addtocounter{PreviousSectionCounter}{-1}
    }% CurrentSectionCounter > 1
    % Set Target to current section
    \phantomsection
    \hypertarget{CurrentSection::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{}%
    %\makeatletter
    \immediate\write1{%
    \string\phantomsection%
    \string\newlabel{CurrentSection::\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}::Title}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{#2}}%
    }%
    \makeatother
    % Set Link to previous section%
    \setcounter{NextSectionCounter}{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}
    \ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{\number\value{LastSectionValue}}{}{%
    \addtocounter{NextSectionCounter}{1}
    }%
    \phantomsection
    \LaTeXStandardSection[#2]{#2}%
    }%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This code is behaving weird? %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{2}{\cfoot{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}}{\cfoot{Wrong number}}% This line always yields "wrong number"
\cfoot{Current section number is: \number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}% This line displays the counter value correctly

\section{test}
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage

\begin{appendices}

\pagestyle{FootLinks}

\section{Section Number A}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\section{B}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\section{Section Number C}
\blindtext
\clearpage

\section{D}
\blindtext

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: An obvious error is in the placement of `\makeatletter`. Also, for having a label referring to the last section number you should use the `totcount` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is way too long. At least the problem can be analyzed:

```
\ifnumequal{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}{2}{%
  \cfoot{\number\value{CurrentSectionCounter}}%
}{%
  \cfoot{Wrong number}%
}% This line always yields "wrong number"
```

The comparison is done only once, at the time, when `\ifnumequal` is executed.
Apparently the value of `CurrentSectionCounter` was different at this time,
thus the footer is set by `\cfoot{Wrong number}` for all following pages.